# pulling and running docker image using Jenkins docker plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to work out how to pull and run a docker image from docker hub inside Jenkins. The docker plugin seems to be the way to go. However, despite the fact that I can find a ton of information in the public domain and stack overflow for building images and pushing them to a registry, I'm struggling to find anything for pulling images and spinning up containers. I can find lots of things which look like this:

```
newImage = docker.build(appNameWithBranch)
docker.withRegistry("https://${registryAddress}", ''){
    newImage.push("${variables.version}")
}
```

Presumably there must be a way of pulling images and spinning up containers using something similar?

Answer (score 2):

basic example using plugins that come along with pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        script {
          // this pulls an image (groovy:2.4) from docker hub and spins up a container based on it. it exits at the end of the block
          docker.image('groovy:2.4').inside {
            sh 'groovy -v'
            // if you have a file called test.groovy in your jenkins workspace, you can "magically" access it
            // inside the container
            sh 'groovy test.groovy'
          }
        }

        // if you want the container to stay up until you shut it down,
        // you can use docker run and include the -d (daemon) flag.
        // here i'm also giving the container the name "nginx-oh-yeah":
        sh 'docker run -d --name nginx-oh-yeah nginx'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however am I correct in thinking that as soon as the call to docker.image . . . inside has completed that the container will no longer be running ?, what I wanted was the ability to keep the container hanging around until the end of the pipeline.

Comment: According to your update if I am reading it correctly the container name is nginx ?, however what confuses me is that this does not appear to be set anywhere explicitly.

Comment: nginx is the image (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). :) updated again.

Comment: I've voted you, however as my reputation is less than 15 it does does appear public-ally. If you want to make a name for yourself in the blogosphere you should write a blog post on this, the information on it out there is very patchy.